# Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'emailForm' before all references to it are out of scope

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have the following function:

```
    private void emailVideoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VideoEMailForm emailForm = new VideoEMailForm();
        emailForm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Which gives me the following warning:

> Warning   1   CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In method
>   'VideoPlayerControl.emailVideoButton_Click(object, EventArgs)', call
>   System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'emailForm' before all references
>   to it are out of scope.

I read this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289(v=vs.80).aspx and gathered that I needed to call .Dispose like so:

```
    private void emailVideoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VideoEMailForm emailForm = new VideoEMailForm();
        emailForm.ShowDialog();
        emailForm.Dispose();
    }
```

But then I get the following warning:

> Warning   1   CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In method
>   'VideoPlayerControl.emailVideoButton_Click(object, EventArgs)', object
>   'emailForm' is not disposed along all exception paths. Call
>   System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'emailForm' before all references
>   to it are out of scope.

Can anyone help me to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What the compiler is trying to say is that if an exception is thrown in `emailForm.ShowDialog()`, `Dispose()` will not get called.

Use a [`using`](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx&ei=WfmtUdP6Co6o0AXpiYHQDg&usg=AFQjCNHVEBQOgRO-i5Hpj4KpVmkoXrLgRw&sig2=v6dE-IkFaNg8QwLYZtkoTQ&bvm=bv.47244034,d.d2k) statement to ensure that it will get called either way.

```
private void emailVideoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (VideoEMailForm emailForm = new VideoEMailForm())
    {
        emailForm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

This is equivalent to this code:

```
private void emailVideoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    VideoEMailForm emailForm = null;
    try
    {
        emailForm = new VideoEMailForm();
        emailForm.ShowDialog();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (emailForm != null) 
        {
            ((IDisposable)emailForm).Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's correct. The compiler will add the `Dispose` call for you.

Comment: does the second code in your example really work? when i do this i get a the name does not exist in the current context error.

Comment: @Bastardo You're right, I fixed it now. The variable must be declared and initialized to null outside the block.

Answer (score 4):

You need the `using` statement, which will call `Dispose()` in a `finally` block to make sure it gets disposed even if an exception is thrown.